# Extract Clip from WPF Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, autocad, clip

I'm having issues trying to not only clip, but to "extract" a portion of a WPF Canvas. So basically I would like the "Clip" to expand to the full size of the window, or convert the clipped item to separate UI Element for exporting to PNG. I write pseudocode because the real code comes from an Autocad model.

```
double oPrintWidth=1169;

Canvas c = new Canvas();
 
c.Width = oPrintWidth * 2.54;
c.Height = c.Width * ratio;

// Define the path to clip
string thisPathData = "M12233 M222333 M3443" // fake
c.Clip = Geometry.Parse(thisPathData);
```

At this point I have the same size canvas but everything other than my path is now black. And the path is still in the original position. I need to now make the clip the entire canvas.

I have played with RenderTransform but I'm lost as what to do next, I'm not so good with matrix calculations.

**Original Canvas** (Collection of UI Elements)

[image: BeforeClip]

**AFTER CLIP**

[image: ClippedImage]

**DESIRED RESULT**

[image: DesiredResult]

Ultimately this would be printed but would prefer to keep it in WPF until last minute to retain VECTOR properties for translating to SVG/XPS/ETC

Comment: What are you drawing on the canvas, just a bunch of UIElements?  Can you post a photo? Perhaps you can create your own canvas so that you have control over the rendering.  That would allow you to access the `DrawingContext` which may be of use.  Otherwise, you can try taking a screenshot and trimming it according to your clip region.

Comment: Yes it is a bunch of UI elements (autocad lines, polylines, etc) but you can imaging a rectangle inside a rectangle. A screen shot im not sure ?

Comment: What is your overall goal here?  It seems like you are printing something.  Perhaps you can describe your problem more?  Anyways, I made a post describing how you can make the `Canvas.Clip` have the same dimensions as the `Canvas`.  By the way, it is nice to see other people integrating WPF and AutoCAD :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a `Clip` of the entire `Canvas` and then apply that `Clip` to the `Canvas` I recommend you let WPF do it for you be setting the [`ClipToBounds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
Canvas c = new Canvas();
c.ClipToBounds = true;
```

If that doesn't suit your needs, I would look at the `Margin`, `ActualWidth`, and `ActualHeight` properties to determine the clip region.  Then create a [`RectangleGeometry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rectanglegeometry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that matches the size of your `Canvas`.

---

**EDIT in response to your comments.**

Well, I've had some time to work at it some more.  What I have been able to do is create a clip region, then I transformed the canvas so that the clip region filled the canvas as much as possible.  I think this is what you are after...

First of all I needed to measure the clipped region:

```
Rect bounds = canvas.Clip.Bounds;
double scaleX = c.Width / (bounds.Right - bounds.Left);
double scaleY = c.Height / (bounds.Bottom - bounds.Top);
```

This scaling information is used to make the clipped region fit exactly to the size of the canvas.
Now, we need to apply transformations to the canvas:

```
TransformGroup group = new TransformGroup();
TranslateTransform move = new TranslateTransform(-bounds.Left, -bounds.Top);
ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(scaleX, scaleY);
group.Children.Add(move);
group.Children.Add(scale);
canvas.RenderTransform = group;
```

So what is happening here?  First of all, the objective is to apply a couple transformations.  We need to center the clipped region (translation) and we need to make the clipped region larger (scale).  Now, when I say clipped region, I mean the contents of that region.  In actuality, we are moving the canvas's rendered output.  Moving the region bounds is not what we want to do.

To do this in WPF, we need to add each transformation we want to a child of a `TransformGroup`.
In this case, we are translating the canvas's output so that its top-left corner is `(0, 0)`  This is necessary because afterwards we will scale the rendered output. So, now, we need to scale the canvas's output so that the image fits as large as it can.  To do this, we need to create a ratio that compares the canvas size to the clipped region size.

Here is the formula for scaling the output:

```
ratio = canvasSize / clippedSize
scaledSize = clippsedSize * ratio
```

Now, scaling the canvas's output will allow the clipped region to appear as large as possible.

Take a look at the results.  Here are images demonstrating the canvas's output before and after the transformations are applied:

#### Before

[image: Before Transformations]

#### After

[image: After Transformations]

I figure I might as well give you all the code I used:

```
Canvas c = new Canvas();
double oPrintWidth=100;
double ratio = .89;
c.Width = oPrintWidth * 2.54;
c.Height = c.Width * ratio;
c.Background = new ImageBrush((ImageSource)FindResource("TestImage")) { Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill };

// Define the path to clip
string newPath = "M 64,64 L 64,128 128,128, 128,64 Z";
c.Clip = Geometry.Parse(newPath);

Rect bounds = c.Clip.Bounds;
double scaleX = c.Width / (bounds.Right - bounds.Left);
double scaleY = c.Height / (bounds.Bottom - bounds.Top);
TransformGroup group = new TransformGroup();
TranslateTransform move = new TranslateTransform(-bounds.Left, -bounds.Top);
ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(scaleX, scaleY);
group.Children.Add(move);
group.Children.Add(scale);
c.RenderTransform = group;

MyBorder.Child = c;
```

And the XAML:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage UriSource="uvtest.jpg" x:Key="TestImage"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Background="Gray">
    <Border x:Name="MyBorder" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I tried setting ClipToBounds = true. The result is a bunch of transparent space around the object. The object I wish to clip is still in its original position

Comment: Are you trying to re-position your object?  If you have position information, you can override the `Canvas.OnRender()` method and interact with the `DrawingContext` parameter to render your object to the canvas.  Also, `DrawingContext` allows you to `Push()` or `Pop()` transformations and clip regions.  If you need to re-position items you may need to look at [`TranslateTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

A clipping region defines the valid places where objects can be rendered, it doesn't re-position things.

Comment: Hello I have added more detail and photo above

Comment: @TimDavis I've updated my answer.  You mentioned having trouble with `RenderTransform`, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much! That was the answer! I didnt need to scale it afterall, just clip the original canvas to the bounding box of the clip.. Brilliant!